# Find Polygon in "Layer A" containing Polygon in "Layer B"

Tags: qgis, python

I haven't found yet someone with the same problem, so I'm posting a new question. The topic seems quite standard, so I'm sure there's a way to do it in QGis.

I have 2 layers:

Region Layer
Postcode Layer

both containing (multi-)polygon features.

I would like to cycle through all the Postcodes, find which is the Region that contains that Postcode, and eventually write the ID of the region inside the Postcode.

So far I've tried to write something in the Python Console, which I can share here:

```
from qgis.utils import iface
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant
_ID_FIELD = 'RS'
_NAME_FIELD = 'GEN'
_PLZ_FIELD = 'plz'
_NEW_ID_FIELD = 'PARENT_ID'
_NEW_NAME_FIELD = 'PARENT_NAME'
Land_layer = iface.mapCanvas().layer(1)
PLZ_layer = iface.mapCanvas().layer(0)
# Create 2 new fields in the layer that will hold the list of neighbors and sum
# of the chosen field.

#PLZ_layer.startEditing()
#PLZ_layer.dataProvider().addAttributes(
#        [QgsField(_NEW_ID_FIELD, QVariant.String),
#         QgsField(_NEW_NAME_FIELD, QVariant.Int)])
#PLZ_layer.updateFields()

## Create a dictionary of all features
PLZ_feature_dict = {f.id(): f for f in PLZ_layer.getFeatures()}
Land_feature_dict = {f.id(): f for f in Land_layer.getFeatures()}
# Build a spatial index
index = QgsSpatialIndex()
print 'PLZ Layer: %s' % PLZ_layer.name()
print 'Landkreis Layer: %s' % Land_layer.name()

for f in Land_feature_dict.values():
    index.insertFeature(f)
    print 'Inserting %s in Landkreis index' % f[_NAME_FIELD]

for f in PLZ_feature_dict.values():
    print 'Working on %s' % f[_PLZ_FIELD]
    geom = f.geometry()
    intersect_ids = index.intersects(geom.boundingBox())
    for id in intersect_ids:
        tempf = Land_feature_dict[id]
        print 'got parent Landkreis %s' % tempf[_NAME_FIELD]
```

Problem is, I'm getting the following error at line

```
intersect_ids = index.intersects(geom.boundingBox())


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "//VAIMUCO9/G114305$/Anwendungsdaten/Desktop/PLZ/ContainerFinder.py", line 34, in  <module>
    intersect_ids = index.intersects(geom.boundingBox())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'boundingBox'
```

Moreover, I'm not really sure that I should use these functions, and even this approach.
Can anybody please suggest me some more clever way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the **Join by Location** tool from the Processing toolbox. It doesn't let you select *which* attributes to join—it will join all of them—but it will give you the postcode of the containing region, using the same fieldname as the region layer.

Use the postcode layer as the target layer, the region layer as the join layer, and take the attributes of the first feature.